# sorting an object by value type

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to sort an **Object** from

> `{"key4": {"name":"joe"},"key3": ["aaa", "bbb"],"key5": {"aaa":["name","joe"]}, "key1": "TypeString", "key2": 0}`

to

> `{"key1": "TypeString", "key2": 0, "key3": ["aaa","bbb"], "key4": {"name":"joe"},"key5": {"aaa":["name","joe"]}}`

my main goal is to sort by the value type and not the the value its self.. ie each value with the type string comes first followed by int then arrays and final object.

Comment: You mean _key_? Keys do not have an order that you can control, so you cannot sort them.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+sort+object+keys) of [Sort JavaScript object by key](/q/5467129/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon no not the key, by the value type, if the value type is a string it comes first, if the value is an integar it comes next if the value is an array it comes next and lastly if the value an object it comes last.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting object property by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

Comment: You should still choose a different data structure; you shouldn’t rely on key order either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print an object, the order of keys is implementation dependent. If you really need to get the keys in insertion order, you can use `Reflect.ownKeys()` (for details, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys)):

```js
const obj = {"key4": {"name":"joe"},"key3": ["aaa", "bbb"],"key5": {"aaa":["name","joe"]}, "key1": "TypeString", "key2": 0};

const keys = Object.keys(obj);
const keysSorted = keys.sort((key1, key2) => getTypeSortId(obj[key1]) - getTypeSortId(obj[key2]));
const objSorted = keysSorted.reduce((o, key) => (o[key] = obj[key], o), {});
console.log(objSorted);
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(objSorted));

function getTypeSortId(value) {
  return (
    typeof value === "string" ? 1 :
    typeof value === "number" ? 2 :
    value instanceof Array ? 3 :
    typeof value === "object" ? 4 :
    5
  );
}
```